# Entity Framework 6 uses an UPDATE when it should be using a DELETE when deleting from a bound DataGridView

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, entity-framework-6

I have a `DataGridView` bound to a `BindingSource` that is bound to `DataMember` `tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction` of `DataSource` `bs_tbl_Series_Manufacturer`, which is itself a `BindingSource` that has a `DataSource` linked to an entity, `ForeNET.tbl_Series_Manufacturer`.  The `DataGridView` in question displays only records related to the current record of `bs_tbl_Series_Manufacturer`.

`tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction` has the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [Fore].[tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction](
    [GM_ORDER_NBR] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Include] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AUS_SRS_CD] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [ManufacturerID] [tinyint] NULL,
    [CNTLG_DLR_CD] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [FAWCode] [varchar](15) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([GM_ORDER_NBR] ASC) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [Fore].[tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction_tbl_Dealer] FOREIGN KEY([CNTLG_DLR_CD])
REFERENCES [Fore].[tbl_Dealer] ([cntlg_dlr_cde])

ALTER TABLE [Fore].[tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction_tbl_Dealer]

ALTER TABLE [Fore].[tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction_tbl_ModelCodes] FOREIGN KEY([FAWCode])
REFERENCES [Fore].[tbl_ModelCodes] ([FAWCode])

ALTER TABLE [Fore].[tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction_tbl_ModelCodes]

ALTER TABLE [Fore].[tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction_tbl_Series_Manufacturer] FOREIGN KEY([AUS_SRS_CD], [ManufacturerID])
REFERENCES [Fore].[tbl_Series_Manufacturer] ([aus_series_cde], [ManufacturerID])

ALTER TABLE [Fore].[tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction_tbl_Series_Manufacturer]

ALTER TABLE [Fore].[tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction_Include]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Include]

CREATE TRIGGER [Fore].[trg_I_tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction] 
   ON  [Fore].[tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction]
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO Fore.tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction (GM_ORDER_NBR, [Include], AUS_SRS_CD, ManufacturerID, CNTLG_DLR_CD, FAWCode)
    SELECT      inserted.GM_ORDER_NBR, inserted.Include, Fore.qry_SOM_OrderInfo.AUS_SRS_CD, Fore.tbl_ModelCodes.ManufacturerID, 
                      Fore.qry_SOM_OrderInfo.CNTLG_DLR_CD, Fore.qry_SOM_OrderInfo.FAWCode
    FROM        inserted INNER JOIN
                      Fore.qry_SOM_OrderInfo WITH (NOEXPAND) ON inserted.GM_ORDER_NBR = Fore.qry_SOM_OrderInfo.GM_ORDER_NBR INNER JOIN
                      Fore.tbl_ModelCodes ON Fore.qry_SOM_OrderInfo.FAWCode = Fore.tbl_ModelCodes.FAWCode
END

CREATE TRIGGER [Fore].[trg_U_tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction] 
   ON  [Fore].[tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction]
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
        DELETE Fore.tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction
    FROM deleted INNER JOIN Fore.tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction ON Fore.tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction.GM_ORDER_NBR=deleted.GM_ORDER_NBR AND Fore.tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction.[Include]=deleted.[Include]
INSERT INTO Fore.tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction (GM_ORDER_NBR, [Include], AUS_SRS_CD, ManufacturerID, CNTLG_DLR_CD, FAWCode)
    SELECT  inserted.GM_ORDER_NBR, inserted.Include, qry_SOM_OrderInfo.AUS_SRS_CD, Fore.tbl_ModelCodes.ManufacturerID, Fore.qry_SOM_OrderInfo.CNTLG_DLR_CD, Fore.qry_SOM_OrderInfo.FAWCode
    FROM    inserted INNER JOIN Fore.qry_SOM_OrderInfo WITH (NOEXPAND) 
                ON inserted.GM_ORDER_NBR = Fore.qry_SOM_OrderInfo.GM_ORDER_NBR INNER JOIN
                      Fore.tbl_ModelCodes ON Fore.qry_SOM_OrderInfo.FAWCode = Fore.tbl_ModelCodes.FAWCode
END
```

My problem is this:

When I delete a row from the `DataGridView`, the row disappears as expected.  At that point, my event code calls `Context.SaveChanges()`  However, the row is not deleted from the database, and the next time I open the form, all the records that I thought I had deleted are still there.  No error messages are displayed at any point.

I bound `Context.Database.Log` to the debug window, and found that when I perform a delete through the `DataGridView`, results similar to the following log output are being generated on executing `Context.SaveChanges()`:

```
UPDATE [Fore].[tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction]
SET [AUS_SRS_CD] = NULL, [ManufacturerID] = NULL
WHERE ([GM_ORDER_NBR] = @0)

-- @0: '6W2CAA' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 50)

-- Executing at 12/02/2014 8:15:51 AM +11:00

-- Completed in 142 ms with result: 1
```

The end result of this SQL statement is that no changes at all are made to the '6W2CAA' record in `[Fore].[tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction]`, since that table has triggers that populate fields `[AUS_SRS_CD]` and `[ManufacturerID]` (amongst others) based on the `[GM_ORDER_NBR]` value, the former fields existing only to obviate the need for an unacceptably slow stored procedure that must look up these values from a number of other tables - it is more acceptable for the lookup load to be shifted to the SQL Server on insert/update.

However, even if these triggers did not exist, in the event of a user deleting then inserting records with the same `[GM_ORDER_NBR]` value, an error would occur since a record with the same (primary key) `[GM_ORDER_NBR]` value would still exist, albeit with NULL `[AUS_SRS_CD]` and `[ManufacturerID]` values.

I would have expected that the SQL statement executed by Entity Framework after a delete from the `DataGridView` would be more like: `DELETE FROM [Fore].[tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction] WHERE ([GM_ORDER_NBR] = @0)`

When I `.Remove` an entity in event code, followed by `.SaveChanges`, the invalid `UPDATE` still occurs first, followed by a `DELETE`.

How can I get Entity Framework to execute the correct `DELETE` SQL statement in response to a `DataGridView` deletion, instead of (rather than in addition to) a wholly inappropriate `UPDATE`?

Comment: Does your datasource allow deleting?

Comment: The datasource does allow deleting - I can delete using SQL on the table in question, or on a different table using EF.

Comment: Have you tried using EF to delete a row without going through the DataGridView?

Comment: I can `.Remove` an entity with the result that the SQL record is deleted on `.Savechanges`

Comment: That would lead me to think the problem is in the DataGridView, not EF.

Comment: When I `.Remove` an entity in event code, the invalid `UPDATE` still occurs first on `.SaveChanges`, then the `DELETE`.

Comment: One more thing to try. Place the EF.Remove inside a try catch block, still separated from the DataGridView, perform the Remove and see if you catch an error. I am also curious about if your table or stored proc has constraints that would prevent the update that EF seems to want to perform before deleting the record.

Comment: `.Remove` doesn't throw an exception.  There are no constraints that prevent nulling the fields that the `UPDATE` nulls, however the triggers would simply reset the null fields to the correct values afterwards.  See my edit for the definition of the table in question.

Comment: Can you remove the triggers temporarily to see if EF completes the Remove/Delete?

Comment: Having disabled the triggers (and the `.Remove`), EF still does an invalid `UPDATE`, which completes successfully.

Comment: Put the `.Remove` back to make sure that it actually deletes the record.

Comment: With or without the triggers, a `.Remove` results in a successful `DELETE` being logged on `.SaveChanges`, but before the `DELETE`, the `UPDATE` still occurs.

Comment: >> However, the row is not deleted from the database, and the next time I open the form, all the records that I thought I had deleted are still there. << Did I misunderstand your statement? It looks like the delete didn't occur from this statement. EF may perform the update to know which records are flagged to delete from the source db. I am trying to eliminate what could be causing the problem with the delete. Please help me understand.

Comment: Adam, I added the `.Remove` to verify that EF was able to delete the SQL record.  Without the `.Remove` (which *should* be unnecessary), the behavior is as I described in my question: When I use the DGV to delete a record, it disappears from the DGV, but the command EF issues is an UPDATE, not a DELETE, and when I reopen the form, the record is back.  Without the triggers, the record would not be visible on the form, but the residual record prevents the record from being added again later by a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akash Kava's answer was enlightening in its revelation that in situations such as the one I described, a record is unlinked, not deleted on "delete".  However, his "answer" was quite inadequate in that, yes, you *can* "bind DGV to Entity Set of `tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction` and set Condition/Predicate for `ForeginKey = Manufacturer DGV's SelectedItem.PrimaryKey`", however, in doing so, you lose the EF tracking and the ability to make changes to the underlying DB's data altogether.

However, Akash Kava's answer was a useful start, so I haven't simply downvoted it.

The solution I found was:

Load the data for `tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction`, and filter it to an `ObservableCollection` that is bound to the `BindingSource`, then add a handler for the `ObservableCollection`'s  `CollectionChanged` event, in which the ObservableCollection's changes are propagated back to the source, from where they will be propagated back to the database on `m_Context.SaveChanges`:

```
Dim m_oc_tDSR = New ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of tbl_Distribution_Stock_Restriction)(From tDSR As tbl_Distribution_Stock_Restriction In m_Context.tbl_Distribution_Stock_Restriction.Local
                                                                                        Where tDSR.AUS_SRS_CD = m_CurrentSeries And tDSR.ManufacturerID = m_CurrentManufacturer
                                                                                        Select tDSR)
bs_tbl_Distribution_Stock_Restriction.DataSource = m_oc_tDSR
bs_tbl_Distribution_Stock_Restriction.ResetBindings(False)
AddHandler m_oc_tDSR.CollectionChanged, AddressOf m_oc_tDSR_CollectionChanged
```

Where the definition for m_oc_tDSR_CollectionChanged is (in essence):

```
Private Sub m_oc_tDOR_CollectionChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
    Select Case e.Action
        Case Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add
            For Each tDOR As tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction In e.NewItems
                m_Context.tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction.Add(tDOR)
            Next
        Case Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove
            For Each tDOR As tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction In e.OldItems
                Try
                    m_Context.tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction.Remove(tDOR)
                Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
                End Try
            Next
        Case Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace
            For CtrA As Long = 0 To e.OldItems.Count - 1
                m_Context.tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction.Remove(DirectCast(e.OldItems, tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction))
                m_Context.tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction.Add(DirectCast(e.NewItems, tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction))
            Next
    End Select
End Sub
```

This allows a filtered entity set that is still tracked.

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework does not issue "Delete" for relations, your DataGridView is bound to an Entity Collection not an Entity Set.

When an entity is removed from EntityCollection, Entity Framework will only delete its association or relation which is identified by a foreign Key. Entity Framework does not know whether to delete it from database or not.

Consider an entity with multiple foreign keys.

```
 Table Products
    PK ProductID
    FK CategoryID (nullable)
    FK VendorID (nullable)
```

Assuming Product is related to Category table and Vendors table. Now when you are removing a product from one category, it is not necessary that it should be deleted from table itself. Because some products may have category and some may not have, similarly some may have vendors defined and some may not.

This is the reason EF does not delete actual record, instead it just sets its foreign key column to null. Which removes an entity from its associated related table, but entity is still present.

If foreign keys are not nullable, then old version of EF used to throw an error. I don't know about the new one yet.

Theoretically, in case of nullable foreign keys, Child Entity can exist without its parent, and in case of non nullable foreign keys, Child Entity can not exist without its parent, in this case relation should be defined correctly. And I had overriden a SaveChanges method to identify non nullable foreign keys and delete the record accordingly if it's associated parent is set to null.

*Answer*

You can bind DGV to Entity Set of tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction and set Condition/Predicate for `ForeginKey = Manufacturer DGV's SelectedItem.PrimaryKey`

Comment: Thanks for the theory.  However my question was: how can I show in a DGV `tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction` records related to the currently displayed `tbl_Series_Manufacturer` records in another DGV, and allow users to add/edit/delete `tbl_Distribution_Orders_Restriction` records, with a minimum of code, either in my front-end or in the database?

Comment: You will have to bind DGV to EntitySet with condition that includes foreign key comparison with primary key of related entity. Is it one to many or many to many?

Comment: Akash Kava, your answer has plenty of explanation of why the problem occurs, but is very short on explanation on how to rectify the problem.  Just how *do* you "set Condition/Predicate for `ForeginKey = Manufacturer DGV's SelectedItem.PrimaryKey`"?  A `BindingSource` bound to an entity doesn't seem able to accept a filter, and I can't add a condition in the entity's Mapping Details, as that is a constant.